# Find and swap part of text in multiple files with Textwrangler

Tags: textwrangler

I'm trying to solve this problem with textwrangler but haven't figured the solution yet.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Suppose I have many emails like this one:

Goodbye

Welcome to the jungle and so on...with much more text...

Hello

---

How would I go to swap "Goodbye" and "Hello" without changing the entire text in between? Notice that the text between can change from email to email.

---

My guess is:

Search for:

(Goodbye)(?s).*?(Hello)

Replace with:

\2 \1

But it doesn't work.

---

I've also tried

Search for:

(Goodbye)|(Hello)

Replace with:

\2 \1

It doesn't work either

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following, make sure you check Grep.

[image: Find-Replace]

Answer (score 0):

You were actually pretty close. One way would be:

Searching for:

```
(Goodbye)(?s)(.*?)(Hello)
```

Replacing with:

```
\3\2\1
```

You'd encounter potentially unexpected effects, if the text included another **Hello**, which could be addressed by changing the search expression to:

```
(Goodbye)(?s)(.*)(Hello)
```

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.